# Custom ArrayAdapter for a Spinner: drop down view not working properly

Tags: android, custom-controls, spinner, adapter

I created a custom `ArrayAdapter` for a `Spinner`. The difference is, that it shows images from an `ArrayList` of a complex class instead of plain text. It works so far. The Images and the radio buttons are displayed as desired. The problem is, that the drop down view doesn't behave correctly: it doesn't close on a click and only the radio buttons are clickable instead of the whole view.

Does anybody has an idea what's wrong? Do I have to implement some kind of `listener` in the `adapter`??

Here's the code of the `getDropDownView` method:

```
@Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView,
                                ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        LinearLayout view=(LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.spinnerimageitem, null);

        ImageView iv=(ImageView)view.getChildAt(0);
        RadioButton rb=(RadioButton)view.getChildAt(1);

        int iImageID=ctx.getResources().getIdentifier(
                "f_"+funcs.get(position).getBitmapSetup(), 
                "drawable", ctx.getPackageName());  
        if(loco.getFunction(iIndex).equals(funcs.get(position)))
            rb.setChecked(true);
        iv.setImageResource(iImageID);
        return(view);
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

set `android:focusable="false"` in your layout for Radio button.

Comment: Fantastic!! That's is, but what's the reason?

Comment: Because Spinner implementation allows only one focusable item in the view. If you set the radio button focus will shift to radio button so item lost it focus ..Thats why you are unable to click

Comment: Thank you! I just noticed, that there is still a small problem: a click on the image selects the item and closes the dialog. But a click on the `RadioButton` checks the `RadioButton` but doesn't close the `dialog`. Any idea for this issue? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @ThomasKusch Have you set onClick Listener for the Radio Button...? set the OnClickListener(Because in this case OncheckedChangeLister and onclickLister both  will be same) for the radio button and when the radio button is checked, close the dialog by code.

Comment: I really apologize to bother you again, but I cannot found much about this issue... How can reach the dialog reference out of the adapter?

Comment: Thank you, Pragnani. I sloved the problem by simply removing the RadioButtons.

Comment: I had a android:clickable=true in my layout, removing that fixed my problem!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. For those who will get this problem later, I found one of solution.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i=1; i<6; i++) items.add("Spinner item "+i);
    spinner.setAdapter(new SpinnerAdapter(this,R.layout.spinner_item_list,items));
}

public class SpinnerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private ArrayList<Boolean> mChecked;
    private ArrayList<String> mValues;
    private Context mContext;
    public SpinnerAdapter(Context context, int resourceId, ArrayList<String> values) {
        super(context, resourceId, values);
        mValues = values;
        mContext = context;
        mChecked = new ArrayList<Boolean>();
        for (int i=0; i<mValues.size(); i++){
            mChecked.add(false);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView,ViewGroup parent) {
            View row= View.inflate(mContext,R.layout.spinner_item_list, null);
            TextView label=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            label.setText(mValues.get(position));
            RadioButton rb = (RadioButton)row.findViewById(R.id.radioButton);
            rb.setFocusable(false);
            rb.setClickable(false);
            rb.setChecked(mChecked.get(position));
            return row;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = View.inflate(mContext,R.layout.spinner_item_top, null);
        TextView label=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        label.setText(mValues.get(position));
        for(int i=0; i<mChecked.size(); i++){
            mChecked.set(i,(i==position));
        }
        return row;
    }
}
}
```

spinner_item_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"                     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView" android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
<RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/radioButton" android:layout_alignParentRight="true"     android:checked="false"/>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

spinner_item_top.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Text"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"     android:id="@+id/textView"></TextView>
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried like this:

```
@Override
public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView,
                            ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;
    if(view == null){
        LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater)
                   tx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view=(LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.spinnerimageitem, null);
    }
     /// your code ....
     return view;
 }
```