# Spinner with custom drop-down view not triggering onItemSelected()

Tags: android, spinner, android-custom-view

I have a Spinner that uses a custom adapter where the getDropDownView() is overridden. Each item in the custom drop-down view is made up of a TextView and a Button.

But, when I run my code, the spinner drop-down items display fine, but clicking them does nothing. The spinner drop-down remains open and spinner.onItemSelected() is not triggered.

**drop_down_item.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dropdown_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:singleLine="true" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/dropdown_button"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Remove"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Custom adapter code**

```
public View getDropDownView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.drop_down_item, parent, false);

    TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.dropdown_text);
    textView.setText(mValues.get(position));        
    Button buttonView = (Button) rowView.findViewById(R.id.dropdown_button));

   return rowView;
 }
```

I create my spinner and adapter with this code:

```
spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.my_spinner);
MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(getViewContext(), R.layout.spinner_item, values);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.drop_down_item);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
...
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
        // Do something here - but this never runs
    }
});
```

So I don't know why onItemSelected() is no longer called?

I was wondering if I need to put a click listener on the drop-down TextView which should in turn trigger onItemSelected() using maybe spinner.setSelection(pos)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution is to set android:focusable="false" in the layout for both the TextView and the Button.

```
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dropdown_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:singleLine="true" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/dropdown_button"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:text="Remove"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Alternatively can also do this in the code:

```
textView.setFocusable(false);
buttonView.setFocusable(false);
```

Found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15000120/custom-arrayadapter-for-a-spinner-drop-down-view-not-working-properly). This works because the Spinner implementation only allows one focusable item in the view. That's why I wasn't able to select the item.

Comment: Do you define OnClickListener in getDropDownView and it is works? in my case when I add any OnClickListener in getDropDownView , the spinner view not close after click.

Comment: This saved my day!!

Answer (score 3):

The Events is basically a interface that Activity implements to recieve the callBack by clicking on the LinearLayout of the DropDown View of Spinner.

```
public class MyArrayAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

String[] values;
int CustomResource;
Context context;
Events events;

public MyArrayAdapter(Context baseContext, int customspinnerview,
        String[] stringArray, Events events) {
    values = stringArray;
    context = baseContext;
    this.events = events;
    CustomResource = customspinnerview;

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return values.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    if (position < values.length)
        return values[position];
    else {
        return null;
    }
}


@Override
public View getView(final int position, final View convertView,
        ViewGroup parent) {
    View rowView = convertView;
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (rowView == null) {
        rowView = inflater.inflate(CustomResource, parent, false);
    }
    TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.dropdown_text);
    textView.setText(values[position]);
    Button button = (Button) rowView.findViewById(R.id.Button_text);
    return rowView;
}

@Override
public View getDropDownView(final int position, View convertView,
        ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView = convertView;`enter code here`
    if (rowView == null) {
        rowView = inflater.inflate(CustomResource, parent, false);

    }
    final LinearLayout parentRelative = (LinearLayout) rowView
            .findViewById(R.id.parent);
    final TextView textView = (TextView) rowView
            .findViewById(R.id.dropdown_text);
    textView.setText(values[position]);
    Button button = (Button) rowView.findViewById(R.id.Button_text);
    rowView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            events.onItemSelectedLister(
                    (AdapterView<?>) parentRelative.getParent(),
                    parentRelative, position, (long) 0);

        }
    });
    // Button buttonView = (Button)
    // rowView.findViewById(R.id.dropdown_button);

    return rowView;
}
```

Events Inteface Its a interface that the Activity implement in order to recieve the callbacks from the Adapter.

```
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;

public interface Events {

public void onItemSelectedLister(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
        int position, long id);
}
```

Activity Implementation.

onItemSelected Implementation is the place where you can do your task.....

```
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import com.example.adapter.MyArrayAdapter;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements Events {
Spinner spinner;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    spinner.setAdapter(new MyArrayAdapter(getBaseContext(),
            R.layout.customspinnerview, getResources().getStringArray(
                    R.array.values), this));
}

@Override
public void onItemSelectedLister(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
        final int position, long id) {
        //perform your Task.......
    Method method;
    try {
        method = Spinner.class.getDeclaredMethod("onDetachedFromWindow");
        method.setAccessible(true);
        try {
            method.invoke(spinner);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException
                | InvocationTargetException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    spinner.post(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            spinner.setSelection(position);
            spinner.setSelected(true);
            ((MyArrayAdapter) spinner.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });

}
}
```

Activity xml File for setContentView

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.customspinner.MainActivity" >

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</Spinner>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Spinner View which is passed to Adapter as layout file.

```
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#99000000"
android:id="@+id/parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/dropdown_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<Button 
     android:id="@+id/Button_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="remove"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

the Code works perfectly fine :) .I have the code perfectly running.

Comment: Thanks very much Shahroze. I'm sure your code is working, but it seems a lot of complexity to achieve something that appears to be very simple?

Comment: you r welcome.Dynamic approach has been used in order achieve the functionality.